# Exporting table with a ST_GEOMETRY column?

Tags: sql, db2, geospatial

I'm currently writing a script that exports data from a list of tables and then imports this data in to an identical copy of the original database, everything seems to work expect one issue:

I cant seem to export tables that have a column containing ST_GEOMETRY data. (The data type of the column is ST_GEOMETRY).

This is a big ask but does anyone know how I can get around this issue?

here is the command I call:

```
db2 export to table_name.del of del "select * from table_name"
```

the error I get is:

```
SQL3529N  The "EXPORT" operation encountered the unsupported data type 
"DB2GSE.ST_GEOMETRY" in column "7".
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell you can't export spatial data with the "regular" db2 export command.

See the topic [Exporting Spatial Data](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/db2sb48.html) at the DB2 information centre. You'll probably also need to read up on [Importing Spatial Data](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc%2Fdoc%2Fdb2sb47.html).

It looks like you can do it either using DB2 Control Center or the "db2se export_shape" and "db2se import_shape" commands (see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/rsbp3018.html)).

Good luck.